# How to visualize trees and splitting values in Matlab's TreeBagger

Tags: matlab, tree, regression, random-forest, cart-analysis

I'm new to TreeBagger in Matlab. I devised 2 simple cases to learn TreeBagger (Random forest). Suppose the independent variable is z:

**First case: 1 variable:**

```
z = {'hi';'hi';'hi';'hi';'hi';'hi';'low';'low';'low';'low';'low';'low'};
```

and the predictor variables is x, and y:

```
x = [1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2];
```

**Second Case: 2 variables**

Same as before but with an additional variable y:

```
y = [1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2];
```

Solving for Case 1:

```
b = TreeBagger(1,x,y, 'Method','classification','NVarToSample',1,'oobpred','on');
```

**What I want:**

Case 1&2: Visualize the classification tree used (I chose one), and also to see the splitting threshold...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody told me the answer. You can view the Tree 1 typing:

```
view(B.Trees{1})
```